# Tool for selectively undo'ing changes to a file managed by SVN

Tags: svn, diff

I need to selectively revert a few lines in a massive file (to be specific, Xcode changed some settings in a project file that I need to revert before committing). I was told there is a tool that will interactively go through the file, diff by diff, and allow you to make changes.

I think it was called svn-view-diffs but I can't find any reference to it.

How may I accomplish this task?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a few choices](http://alternativeto.net/software/winmerge/?platform=mac) for 'merge' tools, all of which are also used for showing differences between files. Most allow you to edit one file inside the tool, either by editing directly or clicking on differences.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/) for Finder will be able to help you

For the exact purpose of seeing diffs though, there is [Diffly](http://lucidmac.com/products/diffly) which is not really a full blown SVN client but will be suitable for what you want.

I think SVNX is the most popular Mac OS client for SVN and it has [FileMerge integration](http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/community/subversion/svnx/screenshots/filemerge/)

Just look at these tools or search for Mac OS diff or SVN client. There are quite a few around and I think there should be some integration with Xcode as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have used tool called svn-view which works similar to CVS view and web module. And i just found web module can be downloaded : http://public.e-tunity.com/web-svn-view/web-svn-view.html

In mean time, Atlassian tools also avialble for that. If you can use Windows environment TortoiseSVN client also help you do that. You can browse repository and see the changes for each files too. http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

Comment: TortoiseSVN comes to mind first, but he is talking about Xcode, so it's a Mac.